# Printing math with user input: Can't convert float to str implicitly

Tags: python

Here's the code :

```
import time
time.sleep(0.7)

while True:
    print("Enter the word 'quit' to quit the calculator :(")
    print("Enter the word 'freenet' to enroll the SSHcrack")
    user_input = input(": ")

    if user_input == "quit":
        break
elif user_input == "freenet":
    num1 = float(input("Enter a Port to Crack:"))
    num2 = input("Enter a Network Name")
    num3 = float(input("Enter an IP-Address,(without symbols!):"))
    result = num3 / num1
    result2 = result / 13
    print("Injectable SSH "+ result2 +"for the Network "+num2)
```

Of course this is just a calculator (I only added the problem code block) and I wanted to test around with the print statement, but it gives me this TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<mypath>", line 51, in <module>
    print("Injectable SSH "+ result2 +"for the Network "+num2)
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states: You have to convert 'float' to str *explicitly*.

This fixes your problem:

```
print("Injectable SSH "+ str(result2) + " for the Network " + str(num2))
```

Even better, use [format strings](https://pyformat.info):

```
print("Injectable SSH {} for the Network {}".format(result2, num2))
```

They help you keeping your message formatting clean, structured and transparent.

Comment: This solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly convert *result2* and *num2* to strings.

```
print("Injectable SSH "+ str(result2) +"for the Network "+ str(num2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're attempting to add a float (decimal) to a string in the line

```
print("Injectable SSH "+ result2 +"for the Network "+num2)
```

"Interjectable SSH " is a string and result2 is a float, and python has no way of knowing how to add a decimal to a string.  Some languages will automatically convert the float into a string, but python will not, hence the error "Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly".

What you need to do is *explicitly* convert both result2 and num2 into strings using the built in str() method.  With the necessary changes, the line wil look something like this:

```
print("Injectable SSH "+ str(result2) +"for the Network "+str(num2))
```

There are a couple other ways that you can do this in python.  If you want to look into that, look up a tutorial in "python string formatting".

Comment: Wow, this is more in-depth, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In python, '+' is used to concatenate string objects. 
Ofcourse in python 2.7, you would have done concatenation/joining of any type of object for a print using a ','.

So, the solution may be like:

```
   print("Injectable SSH "+ str(result2) +"for the Network "+num2)
```